# zynq linux IRQ from PL

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling, device-tree, zynq, irq

I am working with a zynq board , z-turn, and I added two interruptions coming from PL, I edited my device tree with :

```
amba_pl {
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        ranges;

        gpio1@43c20000 {
            #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
            #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
            compatible = "generic-uio";
            gpio-controller;
            interrupt-controller;
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x20 0x4>;
            reg = <0x43c20000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,all-inputs = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-inputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,gpio-width = <0x3>;
            xlnx,gpio2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,interrupt-present = <0x1>;
            xlnx,is-dual = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tri-default = <0xffffffff>;
            xlnx,tri-default-2 = <0xffffffff>;
        };
        gpio2@43c30000 {
            #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
            #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
            compatible = "generic-uio";
            gpio-controller;
            interrupt-controller;
            interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x21 0x4>;
            reg = <0x43c30000 0x10000>;
            xlnx,all-inputs = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-inputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,gpio-width = <0x3>;
            xlnx,gpio2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,interrupt-present = <0x1>;
            xlnx,is-dual = <0x0>;
            xlnx,tri-default = <0xffffffff>;
            xlnx,tri-default-2 = <0xffffffff>;
        };

};
```

and it is mapped to the interruptions , cat /proc/interrupts

57:         52          0       GIC  57  cdns-i2c

61:          1          0       GIC  61  SII902x_det

62:          0          0       GIC  62  logicvc

63:          0          0       GIC  63  0-0053

64:          2          0       GIC  64  gpio1

65:          2          0       GIC  65  gpio2

then I created a module with my interruption and I register them to 96 and 97
(64 + 32) and (65 + 32), the code is :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/irqdomain.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/of_address.h>

#include <asm/exception.h>
#include <asm/mach/irq.h>

//#define INTERRUPT 96
#define INTERRUPT 96

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static irqreturn_t interrupt_hook(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs) {
    printk("interrupt_hook!!\n");

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int __init clcdint_init(void) {
    unsigned int irq;
    unsigned int irqflags;
    int ret;

    irq = INTERRUPT;
    irqflags = IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING;

    ret = request_irq(irq, interrupt_hook, irqflags, "int-test", NULL);

    if(ret != 0) {
            printk("ERROR: IRQ request failed %d", irq);
            printk(" - code %d , EIO %d , EINVAL %d\n", ret, EIO, EINVAL);
    }

    printk("clcdint_init\n");
    return 0;
}

module_init(clcdint_init);

static void __exit clcdint_exit(void) {
    unsigned int irq;
    irq=INTERRUPT;
    free_irq(irq, NULL);
    printk("clcdint_exit\n");
}

module_exit(clcdint_exit);
```

then it is mapped , I am generating the IRQ via a counter and a switch in the board with leds indicating the correct operation, the functions are mapped to:

96:          0          0  zynq-gpio   0  int-test

97:          1          0  zynq-gpio   1  int-test2

right after the insmod I get 
\0x1b[0;31mZ-turn#\0x1b[m insmod driverirq146.ko
SUCCESS: Registered IRQ 97
clcdint_init2

but the IRQ is not happening frequently , it happens once or twice as you see in the counter of the /proc/interrupts , maybe it is in the software side , if anybody has any tip.

Comment: `irq` in `request_irq` is the Linux number, not the hardware!

Comment: tks ! I found that out and set the 0x20 and 0x21